# How to initialize each object when allocating an object array

Tags: c++, arrays, object, initialization

In C++, I have a class CMyObject as follows, where CData is another class name:

```
Class CMyObject
{
CMyObject(CData& Data): m_Data(Data) {};
virtual ~CMyObject(void);

private:
  const CData& m_Data;
}
```

When allocate one CMyObject instance, I can do as follows:

```
P = new CMyObject(MyData);
```

However, if I want to create an array of CMyObject, then can I do as follows?

```
P = new CMyObject(MyData)[10];
```

Comment: Use a vector: `std::vector<CMyObject> p(10, CMyObject(Data));`

Comment: Do you need to initialize each object of the array with something different?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an initialization list (I used 4 to save some typing, but you get the idea):

```
CMyObject* P = new CMyObject[4]{MyData, MyData, MyData, MyData};
```

But better still, use an `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<CMyObject> P(10, MyData);
```

Comment: will std::vector<CMyObject> P(10, MyData) consuming more memory than new CMyObject[10]?

Comment: @user2704265 A very small amount. About the size of two pointers.